# How to enable in-place editing in an asp:GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, inplace-editing

How can i add edit boxes, and read their values during submit, with an `asp:Repeater`?

---

i have an `asp:GridView` which is displaying a read-only (i.e. non-editable) set of data, e.g.:

[image]

How can i enabled the cells of the `GridView` to be editable, e.g (Photoshop Mockup):

[image]

> **Note:** i didn't mockup in Photoshop an edit box into every row and column (cause it was taking too long). You still get the idea.

- How can i convince an `asp:GridView` to show an edit-box in each cell?
- If i do convince the `asp:GridView` to show an edit-box, how do i "read" them `OnClick` of **Save** button?

### Bonus Chatter

i would not be opposed to using an `asp:Repeater`, manually placing `<INPUT>` controls. My confusion then is about how to read each input during the `OnClick` of the **Save** button. And although i would be perfectly happy to use a repeater, and a GridView might not be able to accomplish what i want making the repeater the only possibility, this question is about a GridView.

- If the GridView *can* do it: great; how?
- If the GridView *cannot* do it: that's an answer too.

Comment: That entire column should be editable, right? Not just a single row?

Comment: @Blachshma Yes. Likely the user would want/need to edit all items.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried by setting up the `EditIndex` property of the `DataGrid`?

Example:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" onrowediting="grdProducts_RowEditing" 
    ID="grdProducts">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
    protected void grdProducts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        this.grdProducts.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        This.BindGrid();
    }
```

Note that you have to re-bind your grid

Usually you save the data per row, which means, you have an edit link in each row and after you enter edit mode, a save button and optionally a cancel button appear which will allow you to save the values of that specific row

Following this approach is trivial when using the `GridView`:

```
    protected void grdProducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // old values for the current row
        var oldValues = e.OldValues;

        // new (updated) values for the current row
        var newvalues = e.NewValues;

        // Exit edit mode
        this.grdProducts.EditIndex = -1;

        // Update the grid
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

In the grid markup just add the following:

```
    onrowupdating="grdProducts_RowUpdating"
```

If you need to specify custom controls when editing or when displaying the cell data in read-only mode, use grid templates:

```
       <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
```

Comment: The problem with the `RowEditing` event is that you can only edit data *per-row*, and you can only edit one row at a time, and you have to have an *Edit* button command link, which the user has to click first.

Comment: what's `This.BindGrid()`?

Comment: Just a custom function to bind the grid, a function where you usually would set the grid's datasource property

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using a GridView, but you'll produce quite a lot of code if you have many columns.

First make all columns in the GridView TemplateFields. In my sample I will use just one column. Like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="test" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Foo" SortExpression="foo">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="FooText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Foo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <!-- other cols here -->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Save_Click" />
```

Then in your code behind for the Save button you can iterate over the rows in the GridView:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in test.Rows)
{
    string val = ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("FooText")).Text;
    <!-- other cols here -->
    //do something with all the values you have parsed from the row
}
```

Comment: If you use `Bind` rather than `Eval` in your `ItemTemplate` it should autoupdate the underlying data value?