# How to inline edit with gridview with 3 layer architecture in ASP .Net WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, n-tier-architecture

Does anyone have resources and links to share with me for above topic? I googled around, but Just normal inline gridview editing in WebForm,  and I couldn't really apply to use for my project.  I am developing an app with VS2010 version. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable in-place editing in an asp:GridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088887/how-to-enable-in-place-editing-in-an-aspgridview)
3 layer architecture doesn't make any difference ...

Comment: Thank, anyway. I have figured it out how to do this.